# make indicator work during a specific period of time

Tags: pine-script

I have an alert indicator and I want it to work during a period of time from monday to friday. The time period should be between 8 am and 7 pm. How can I achieve this?
This is what I have so far:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

// 1 hour is 3600000 milliseconds
// to convert to 8 hours, multiply 8 with 3600000 = 28800000

startTime = 28800000 // 08.00
endTime = 68400000 // 19.00
currentTime = timenow

if (currentTime >= startTime and currentTime <= endTime)
plot(close)
```

I get following error when saving:
*line 16: Mismatched input 'plot' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. I am not sure whether I should use `t[1]` or just `t` in the `plotshape()` and `alertcondition()` but both ways seems to work. If anyone is interested in the code, here it is:

```
//@version=4

//Shows buy-signal when price crosses over SMA on lower timeframe, while price is above SMA on higher timeframe. 
//The opposite is true for sell signals.
//For this indicator to work properly, present chart needs to be lower than the selected higher timeframe.
//You can also set it to work only during a specific time. 
//For more information on how to use time: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.html


study("MA Cross MTF Alert", shorttitle="MA Cross MTF Alert", overlay=true)

timeInput = input('0200-1330', title="Indicator will work during following time (has to be according to the exchange's timezone):")
t = time(timeframe.period, timeInput)

smaPeriod = input(5, title="Period SMA")
pricetype = input(close, title="Price Source For The SMA")
higherTfRes = input(title="Higher timeframe", type=input.resolution, defval="60")

priceHighTf = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTfRes, pricetype[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
smaHighTf = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTfRes, sma(priceHighTf, smaPeriod)[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

smaLowTf = sma(pricetype, smaPeriod)

Buy =  crossover(close, smaLowTf) and close > smaHighTf
Sell = crossunder(close, smaLowTf) and close < smaHighTf
plot(smaLowTf)
plot(smaHighTf, color=color.black, linewidth=2)
plotshape(Buy[1] and t, style=shape.circle, location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(Sell[1] and t, style=shape.circle, location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, size=size.tiny)
alertcondition(Buy[1] and t, title="Buy alert", message="Buy {{ syminfo.root }} - MA Cross alert")
alertcondition(Sell[1] and t, title="Sell alert", message="Sell {{ syminfo.root }} - MA Cross alert")
```